# Export content from an ecommerce site without using the Backend

Tags: database, e-commerce, volusion

I have a site that I'm looking to transfer to Volusion. Importing tabled content into Volusion's a breeze, it's getting it tabled that's an issue. The old site has no real ability to export, nor do I know how to get at it's database. I'm thinking there must be some sort of script I can write to take the content from the frontend and download it in some sort of list that I can put into a CSV, and put into Volusion.

www.twincitygreetings.com

Any suggestions? I'm hoping to get in the image directory as well and download all them for upload to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need at the very least a file with product code, product name, weight and price.

Looking at the URL you provided it doesn't appear that the products their follow any type of orderly structure where you can target the images folder or products based on a known piece of information like a products code. Unless the back-end has some type of product export function you may have no choice but to recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this yet or not, but I would suggest scraping the data providing you have the information on the old site currently.  This can be done easily using vbscript and excel, or if you aren't very savvy at coding you could look at a piece of software called mozenda.  There are a whole variety of methods that can be used to scrape data, all of them pretty easy to learn with a bit of research.  Basically you write a script that will crawl your dom and extract the data (to xml works best in my experience)
Hope this helps.